# Confused by low quality question asked by user with a history of reasonable questions

Tags: discussion

I came across this question today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324747/not-set-to-an-instance-of-the-object and flagged it as a duplicate of the ever popular [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

After flagging, I noticed the user asking has 1.2k rep and has asked some reasonable questions and has a couple of good answers in the recent past.

This seems at odds with the low quality of this question, is this a case of an account being hijacked or something similar? Or maybe just a brain-fart on an off day.

Comment: They did say "*I am coding first time in VB today in my life.*" - that may well be true: ["*Please help on VB.NET equivalent of this from C# - on hold*"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34303409/please-help-on-vb-net-equivalent-of-this-from-c-sharp) - 22 hours ago, -6 votes overall... Looking back through their history, they have asked 157 questions, about seven on the first page had negative overall votes. It looks like they've accumulated reputation slowly but steadily over three years. 1.2k reputation doesn't make a good user; 1 reputation doesn't make a bad user.

Comment: @WaiHaLee, that's true, but that error is pretty standard for .net programming.

Comment: Skimming over their entire history, they have notably more negatively scored questions than positively scored questions, but with most being just straight 0.  Of the positive questions, most look like they're not appropriate for the site; they're just popular but unhelpful questions that people like to upvote even though they don't produce quality content.  You've just found yet another bad question from a help vampire that was helped *once again* to avoid learning how to actually program.

Comment: @Steve So given that you're seeing someone who's been programming for *at least* 5 years making a mistake like that should tell you something about them.  This is what happens when you just give people fish; you're still feeding them 5 years later.

Comment: I've seen people with high rep make blatant recommendation requests. It's weird to see but it does happen.

Comment: You're referring to a tag where >20k users post answers [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33620310/1842065), I'd say [expect the unexpected](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bJxrFe).